# text-overflow:ellipsis does not work with <br> in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

When using **text-overflow:ellipsis** and there is **br tag** in markup in IE then second line is not cut off.

**Markup:**

```
<div class="text">
    really long text
    <br/>
    really long text
</div>
```

**Css:**

```
.text{
    width: 50px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

**Output:**

```
reall...
really long
```

**Expected (how it works in other browsers):**

```
reall...
reall...
```

Here is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y9ur5ytr/)

Comment: Thanks, will add the fiddle to that report

Answer (score 0):

This could be one of the solutions for IE

`<div class="text">
    really long text
    <br/>
    <div class="text">really long text 
    </div>
</div>`