# text-overflow: ellipsis not working in IE10

Tags: css, internet-explorer-10

I have a div wrapper to wrap some text which I want to ellipse out when it exceeds 
the wrapper width. Below is my HTML and CSS it works perfectly fine in chrome. Any one explain whats going wrong with IE10.

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="my-title">Lorem, Ipsum 
                         <br>Our TYPE
                         <br>Confirmed
                         <br>simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
    </div>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.my-title {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    word-wrap: normal;
    width: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
    width: 500px
}
```

**PLUNKER LINK**

http://plnkr.co/edit/iAO3ZMT3IM5wwoN83QlY?p=preview

Comment: IE, Edge are simply bad, really bad browsers built by mistake.

Comment: Try removing the `width` value or else use a pixel value instead of percentage

Comment: Multiline text with <br> tags is cause - even IE11 can't display it propely, BUT, if you remove line breaks - it works. :) (not sure about IE10, though)

Comment: Added plunker link to the question.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan the link provided definitely is not the one which will work in my div which has <br> element.

Comment: @Yes, it in the same. IF you read trough all the answers and comments you'll see that IE is buggy about `<br>`. What's not clear? Is there something I'm missing? So it's a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14664195/text-overflowellipsis-doesnt-work-on-ie?lq=1 (since basically it's about the same issues in IE)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan The reason for me to use <br> is to add text in next line. If ever any line exceeds the wrapper width it needs to add ellipsis. I have also tried to create div for each individual line which didn't work.

Comment: @Prashanth have you seen the comments on that page where it says that if you use `<br>` it'll **not work in IE**?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Got it. Do you have any solution to show the text in next line and apply the ellipsis if ever it exceeds the wrapper width ?

Comment: @Prashanth hmm I said goodbye to such IE issues a long time ago... since most of them cost my company a lot of *my time*. I'm not sure it's possible without hacks - I'm also quite sure that similar questions are already here on SO. Ellipsis is a really common thing.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Thank you for the help. Unfortunately we need to deal with IE and need to find if there is any way of doing it.

Comment: @Prashanth even using hacks and JS?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan  Appreciate your patient replies.Tried making the <br> to separate div's unfortunately it didn't work. As far as JS haven't thought of going there before giving up on a CSS solution.

Comment: @Prashanth I tried every possible solution I could find (without using brain) and really none worked in IE and even Edge. If I figure out some nice trick I'll keep you informed.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan thanks.

Comment: @Prashanth do you use any PHP or other server-size stuff on your website? I know that it's not a solution in the world of responsive websites... but you could manually trim clamp the text after N characters and add `&hellip;` ellipsis. Or simply find a solution that uses jQuery or plain JS.

Comment: No ours is just a standalone windows application.

Comment: Here is some kind of accepted answer and maybe it is appropriate to this problem also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18691919/ie10-text-overflow-ellipsis-not-working

Answer (score 0):

You could just eliminate the page breaks and put each of the lines in their own div such as [this](http://codepen.io/SkyHyzer/pen/wKwKvp).

```
<div style="width: 200px;">
  <div>Lorem, Ipsum</div>
  <div>Our TYPE</div>
  <div>Confirmed</div>
  <div class="my-title">
    simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Which is basically the same as this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/31035811/383904

Comment: Thanks. That will work but somehow my data is getting generated by backend which I need to be using with <br>. I will take that answer if there is nothing else I am missing with  CSS may be this is the only way in IE10. @RokoC.Buljan really appreciate your passion.